# Dynamically change the position of a block, base the position on a centered block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to place a block (the red one) on top right of an another one (the green one) which is centered in the window.
The green block is a picture.
How could I accomplish that ?[image: the green centered block, and the red one]

```css
#flag {position: absolute; background-color: green; height:6vw; width:15vw; color: white; text-align:center; }
#introduction {display: table; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; width: 60%; height: 100vh;}
#caser img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
#caser {padding-top:6vw; padding-bottom:6vw; display: table-cell; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flag">
    <a class="linkme" id="go" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl">
        Hello
    </a>
</div>

<div id="introduction">
    <div id="caser"><a href="http://www.google.fr">
        <img src="http://bhrabbitrescue.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/cute-bunnies-tongues-6.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was posting my first idea... But was finally not so good. You should look for a script to find the exact position of the image in the page to calculate the position to give to your green block. Look for [jQuery offset](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your html. Here is my code. Added new div `caser-inner` in `caser` inside which added `flag` div. Also changed `flag` css to place it.

Html-

```
<div id="introduction">
    <div id="caser">
      <div class="caser-inner">    
      <div id="flag">
          <a class="linkme" id="go" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl">
              Hello
          </a>
      </div>
      <a href="http://www.google.fr">
          <img src="http://bhrabbitrescue.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/cute-bunnies-tongues-6.jpg">
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css-

```
#flag {position: absolute; background-color: green; height:6vw; width:15vw; color: white; text-align:center; top: -6vw; right: -15vw;}
#introduction {display: table; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; width: 60%; height: 100vh;}
#caser img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
#caser {padding-top:6vw; padding-bottom:6vw; display: table-cell; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;}
.caser-inner{position: relative;}
```

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/qu74p7p2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your (`div` that defines it) red element inside your green (`div` that defines it) element.

As the green element already has an `absolute position` you just need to use these CSS rules in the green element:

```
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
```

If you want to do this dynamically your need:

1) Define an event to trigger it (for example a mouse click);

2) Use jQuery to pass the CSS rules we defined above inside that event.

For example:

```
$("#the trigger element id here").click(function(){
    $("#your green element id here").css({"position": "absolute", "top": "0", "right": "0"})
})
```

You can use the event you want and you need to have jQuery .

Answer (score 0):

First, rearrange your html so that both elements are children of introduction. From there, you can set a display: flex property on intro. This allows use to stack the two elements, using flex-direction:column. From there, take the link styling off of the #flag div and assign the css rules to the `<a>` tag. By setting the #flag div to be 100% width, block-level div, we can push the button all the way to the right-hand side of the image content with justify-content: flex-end

```css
#flag {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

#flag a {
  background-color: green; 
  height: 6vw; 
  width: 15vw; 
  color: white; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#introduction {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: 
  margin-left: 20%; 
  margin-right: 20%; 
  width: 60%; 
  height: 100vh;
}

#caser img {
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}

#caser {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="introduction">
  
  <div id="flag">
    <a class="linkme" id="go" target="_blank"             href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl">Hello</a>
</div>
  
  
    <div id="caser"><a href="http://www.google.fr">
        <img src="http://bhrabbitrescue.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/cute-bunnies-tongues-6.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```